# Manjaro-i3: change default for open as terminal?

Tags: manjaro, i3

Recently moved from Ubuntu to Manjaro-i3.

I installed sqlitebrowser and when I first opened it I accidently chose to open it as a terminal instance.

How can I change that choice so I don't have a terminal instance running along side the GUI.

Comment: I too recently moved from Ubuntu to Manjaro-i3. My problem was with the dolphin file manger.

Answer (score 2):

Those configuration files are kept under `~/.config/dmenu-recent`. Given the request, the following one-liner should delete the offending line in the config file:

```
sed -i '/sqlitebrowser/d' ~/.config/dmenu-recent/terminal
```